# How can I pass the value of a var to print in my TextView

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to print the values of **var list2: [String] = []** in my UITextView

I'm writing this code, but it gives error

```
@IBOutlet weak var notesShow: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    notesShow.text = list2
}
```

Comment: Array store values at index path starting from 0 .Now if you only have one big string in your array then it is at index 0 .Just use a for loop to get that index value and assign to your text view.

Comment: My list2 is a Global Variable and I want to print the data in TextView, what if I declare list2 as a simple String ? How can I then print the data in the TextView ?

Comment: Table view or text view?

Comment: I've managed a way to do so, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list2 is an array.  You cannot assign an array of string to a string.  [Join](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2429146-joined) the elements with a line break into a single string

```
notesShow.text = list2.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: how do I declare list2 just as a simple string ? and print it in the TableView ?